# 3d (interactive) plot and regression line in R

Tags: r, plot, 3d, regression, linear-regression

I have x,y,z data that I would like to plot in R together with a regression line I fitted to data. Prefereably interactive plot, but a static would be fine as well.

I am currently using the 'car' package to generate an interactive plot. How can I add the regression line?

```
    library(car)
    data(iris)
    f <- lm(iris$Sepal.Length ~ iris$Sepal.Width + iris$Petal.Length)
    scatter3d(x=iris$Sepal.Length, y=iris$Sepal.Width, z=iris$Petal.Length, point.col = "blue", surface=FALSE)
```

Or any other package that could make such a plot in R?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean a regression plane?

Comment: The estimated regression function stored in `f` is not a line but a plane. `scatter3d(x=iris$Sepal.Length, y=iris$Sepal.Width, z=iris$Petal.Length, point.col = "blue")`should do the trick.

Comment: I see. Is it possible to calculate a regression line, not a plane?

Comment: Oh, what a stupid question of me... Of course, I cannot, sorry.